# SVN 'Unexpected end of svndiff input' error

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm having a problem with svn, where running 'svn up' produces the following error:

```
svn: Unexpected end of svndiff input
```

Ironically, running 'svnadmin verify repository_path' also returns the same error. It happens on existing working copies and brand new working copies too.

Anybody had and solved this problem before? We've been using svn for a number of years and know our way around pretty well, but this one has us stumped!

Answer (score 1):

if

```
svnadmin verify repo/path
```

returns the same error, then your repository is corrupted (bad harddrive maybe?).

try running

```
svnadmin recover repo/path
```

if that doesn't help, you might have to restore your repository from a backup.